# How do I update existing elements in a structure?

Tags: c, file, data-structures, methods, structure

I am working a program that has to function like an address book. However, I am having trouble trying to have a function that allows the user to update an existing contact's information. I had attempted to modify and use existing functions (as I have one that creates, searches,and deletes a contact) to do this.The code below is how I am trying to approach the problem.

The code:

```
void updateContact(){
    //Variables
    addressbook tempBook1;
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("contact.txt", "r");
    char add[30], city[20], state[20], zip[10], email[30];
    char name[20];
    char name1[20], phone[20];
    int menuChoice;


    //Prompt Output
    system("cls");
    outputSearchPrompt()
    scanf("%s", name);

    //Search and Update Contact
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s \n", name1, phone, add, city, state, zip, email) != EOF) {
        if (strcmp(name, name1) == 0) {
            displayMenu()
            printf("Enter the number of what you want to update");
            printf("or enter anything else to exit:");
            scanf("%d", &menuChoice);

            switch (menuChoice) {
            case 1:
                printf("Enter the updated name:");
                //scanf("%s", tempBook1.name);
                break;
            //More Menu Options for All Elements
            default:
                printf("Okay");
            }

        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("\n\tPRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE");
    _getch();
    main();
}
```

Comment: Please create a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Generally you can't update a text-file on the fly, because if the length of the new line is different from the old then you might be left with old data on the line (now being "garbage") or overwriting the next line. The common way is to read all into a new temporary file, writing the new data when you write the record that should be changed, then rename the temporary file as the original data file.